# Identifying the Crown and Root Ends of a Slab of wood

Tags: wood-identification

**What i have**:
An almost square slab from the centre of a [Neem tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azadirachta_indica) trunk, with dimensions 30" x 29" x 1.5", with it's bark along the width dimension. As the slab is from the centre of the tree, it's cracking along the core at the centre of the growth rings. It's cut square at the top and bottom so it is able to stand up straight, and has no appreciable twisting.
[image: The slab, slightly sanded, with the wide side of the crack at the bottom]
[image: One end grain, showing the core]
[image: Other side of the slab, slightly sanded, containing an embedded nail grown over]
**What I'm planning**: I'll be using the 2 halves (after breaking the slab along the cracked core) as legs for a slab work table, with a couple of additional supports to stabilize the whole structure.

**What I want to know**: How do I identify which end of the slab was towards the root and which end is towards the crown of the tree?

**Why**: I remember reading something about keeping vertical pieces of wood aligned such that the root end should be down and the crown end towards the top (don't remember the source, so no reference unfortunately).

I have no knowledge of woodworking terminology, so please let me know if I have stated anything incorrectly or if anything is unclear.

**EDIT**:

- New pics of the slab, with some sanding done using a 5" sanding disk attachment on a Bosch rotary grinder.
- One side has a metal nail in it , embedded in the tree, and the cut mark  where the resawing machine had issues cutting through the nail can be seen across the whole slab.
- <del>I have another 45 inch section of the slab (it's at the wood shop, to be delivered with a few other bigger purchases). When it's delivered, I'll add a picture of the 2 sections together, which should hopefully give a better idea.</del>
- It might be possible to figure it out with the orientation of knots (branch points) pointing upwards towards the crown, which I'll check on when the rest arrives but this section does not seem to have any.

Comment: I will be very interested to find out if there's anything to this "keep the tree right side up" theory, or if it's an old wives tale. If there's merit to it, there are a _lot_ of houses in the US with their studs "upside down" (by sheer probability).

Comment: I would hazard that wider is lower, so the slab in the photo is up-side-down

Comment: @EliIser Not necessarily Many, perhaps most trees get wider near the top of the main trunk, especially if there's a crotch where the trunk forks into two smaller parts.

Comment: Well that 3rd pic is the best evidence, and going by conventional thinking that is towards the top, meaning the slab is oriented as it was in life. *"I'll add a picture of the 2 sections together, which should hopefully give a better idea."* Why? Like both Answers say, it doesn't matter — this orientation has no importance in furniture making.

Comment: @Graphus all that was added before any answers. I haven't removed it to from the question yet, but looks like I should.

Comment: I was fairly sure that's not how the Question read when I posted my Answer and checking I posted it about four minutes before your update that included that bit :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, for your application, it makes absolutely no difference, unless the esthetics of one orientation or other is superior, which way you use the wood.   Structurally, and in terms of machining for construction, the crown/root orientation makes absolutely no difference.

That said, in your picture, I am highly certain that the crown end up is up.   You can generally (and I mean generally, not always) tell in a slab by noting the orientation of branch roots embedded in the wood.   In this case, there are three of them very near the pith at the top of your slab.   Note in particular the bottom one.   The knot has a comet-tail like appendage winding down in the slab, sightly toward the pith.   This is the branch root.   On nearly all angiosperm tree species, branch roots are long and with relatively gentler curves toward the root, and shorter with more acute curves toward the crown.   Plus, and fairly diagnostically, when a branch is removed, there are changes in the wood of the branch root relative to the still "live" wood that surrounds it.   Often this results in discoloration ranging from dramatic darkening, to more subtle shading.   You can see this fairly clearly in the third branch root in your slab.   Such discoloration rarely spreads far upwards, but often affects the entire branch root in the direction of the root.

This is not foolproof - you have to discernable branch roots to work from, to start with, and it's not unheard of for a branch to grow uncharacteristically and give no or ambiguous symbols.   But it's pretty rare, and you've clearly got a piece of bole that grew straight and shed it's early branches normally.

Comment: I've changed the pictures to those taken after I sanded the slab a bit with a sanding disk attachment on a rotary grinder. Cleaner view of the knots, and both sides added. Please re-view and reassess.

Answer (score 4):

> **What I want to know:** How do I identify which side of the slab was towards the root and which side is towards the crown of the tree?

I don't think there's any reliable way of doing this in all cases. There *are* tips about how, but so much depends on the wood that the reality is you can't always tell.

> **Why:** I remember reading something about keeping vertical pieces of wood aligned such that the root side should be down and the crown side towards the top (don't remember the source, so no reference unfortunately).

Don't worry about the lack of a source because the context may have been (is likely to have been<sup>1</sup>) different. Here it doesn't apply.

For furniture work, and actually much outside this, as a rule not only do people not even attempt to orient boards this way but frequently boards are oriented on a *purely visual basis*. So you might deliberately flip some boards end for end, meaning some end up 'upside down', because you want a specific grain pattern in the assembled piece.

---

<sup>1</sup> Where you may have read about ensuring this orientation is for exterior siding or fenceboards where it has an effect on long-term weathering, [example](https://nakamotoforestry.com/installing-wood-siding-plank-grain-direction/). I want to highlight however that the term "shou sugi ban" is [now known not to be correct](https://www.popularwoodworking.com/finishing/yakisugi/), although given the difficulty in eradicating mistakes in terminology I doubt we'll see it disappear any time soon!